# How to display a simple primefaces datagrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid

I thought I'd try and get a primefaces datagrid working with my JSF code, but I always got "no results found". So I'm trying to set up a simple example but I get the same error messages so I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

I have the following backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean {

private static final Logger logger =    Logger.getLogger("datagrid.ejb.CarBean");
private List<Car> cars;

public CarBean() {
    cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    cars.add(new Car("myModel",2005,"ManufacturerX","blue"));
    logger.log(LogLevel.INFO, "added car");
    //add more cars
}

public List<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}
}
```

And the following xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 <h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}" columns="3"
rows="12"layout="grid">
<p:column>
<p:panel header="#{car.model}">
  <h:panelGrid columns="1">
<p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/#{car.manufacturer}.jpg"/> 
<h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
</h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
</p:column>
</p:dataGrid>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

I can see from the logs and debugger that the CarBean is instantiated but still I get the no records found error. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Zobbo

Comment: Do you have correct import `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`? Also don't initialize fields in constructor, use method with `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Comment: There is a working example in the PrimeFaces showcase. It is simple to. Try that, find the differences with your code...

Comment: The import is correct. The constructor intialisation is copied from the example from the primefaces manual. However the showcase example is better so I'll try and figure it out using that, as Kukeltje suggested. Thanks for your help.